# Media query style overriden by default style

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm creating a responsive page using CSS Media Queries. I can see in Chrome's developer tools that the media queries are working, however, they are not overriding my default styles. For example, take these styles:

```
#hero .text {
  margin: 150px;
}

@media all (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 1px) {
  #hero .text {
    margin: 80px;
  }
}
```

In my browser, if I resize to 1024px wide, I can see that the all the above styles are being requested BUT the default style (with margin 150px) is what is finally used.

ANy idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**change this**

```
@media all (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 1px) {
  #hero .text {
    margin: 80px;
  }
}
```

**to**

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      #hero .text {
        margin: 80px;
      }
    }
```

and

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
          #hero .text {
            margin: 80px;
          }
        }
```

and this one below,

```
.text { /*removed #test */
  margin: 150px;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew:from which resolution are you resizing it to 1024px

Comment: @Andrew check now..!!

Comment: @Andrew:one is max-width and other is min-width

Comment: @Andrew:i think now my answer will be perfect for you..!!

Comment: This would require me wrapping my entire stylesheet in a media query. It would be more efficient to just use "!important" on the margin value.